# How to have a background colour for each letter except for the ' . '(dot) or ' , '(coma) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, counter

I want to have a background colour for each letter except for the **'.'(dot)**, **','(coma)** or the **'-'(minus)**, when I try to use the **backgroundColor** parameter in the **TextStyle()** it gives a background the colour to the  **'.'(dot)**, **','(coma)** and **'-'(minus)** as well and I don't want that.

I'm using the [animated_flip_counter](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_flip_counter) for the animation.

My code:

```
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black54,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.32),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      // height: 50,
                      // // width: 500,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      // alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 2),
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.32),
                      ),

                      child: AnimatedFlipCounter(
                        value: _counter,
                        fractionDigits: 2, // decimal precision
                        decimalSeparator: '.',
                        thousandSeparator: ',',
                        prefix: '-',
                        curve: Curves.bounceOut,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          letterSpacing: 5,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

What i want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would use RichText widget to apply different styles to parts.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: and how would this be applied in the code I have above?

Comment: it won't. RichText is a perfectly correct answer for general case when you need to vary the styles within text, but the package you're using only allows to pass a num value. any solution has limitations of customization

Comment: As you are using the package you can apply the style to text in the package's dart file. You can find it in dart packages. Search for decimalSeperator, thousandSeparotor, etc and apply style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent)

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; in package's dart file as you will be using material transparent. And, don't forget to run flutter pub get after you edit the external package.